# malloc(): memory corruption (fast), std::vector and std::stringstream

Tags: c++, stdvector, stringstream

So... Got a weird one. In the following code, I receive a

```
*** Error in `./a.out': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00000000011165f0 ***
```

On the while loop line of the below function.

```
std::vector<std::string> stringSplitter(const std::string & toSplit, char split) {
    std::stringstream stream(toSplit);
    std::vector<std::string> toReturn;
    std::string current;

    while (std::getline(stream, current, split))
        toReturn.push_back(current);

    return toReturn;
}
```

I have been able to reproduce the error by sending it something like

```
SEND allenh1 passwd sup?
```

But the function works as intended when I send it

```
COMMAND allenh1 passwd room1
```

Any ideas?

---

The call to this function comes from the following lines in another function:

```
   FILE * fssock = fdopen(fd, "r+");

// Read character by character until a \n is found or the command string is full.
   while (commandLineLength < MaxCommandLine &&
    read( fd, &newChar, 1) > 0 ) {

    if (newChar == '\n' && prevChar == '\r') {
        break;
    }

    commandLine[ commandLineLength ] = newChar;
    commandLineLength++;

    prevChar = newChar;
}

// Add null character at the end of the string
// Eliminate last \r
commandLineLength--;
    commandLine[ commandLineLength ] = 0;

printf("RECEIVED: %s\n", commandLine);

std::string input(commandLine);
std::vector<std::string> bySpace = stringSplitter(input, ' ');
```

Comment: Also, after sending the output into a text file, I ran a `cat -a` on the file and found no unintended characters.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in this code. Post more code here. In which way you are calling this function. From where you are getting data ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post too much code... After backtracing with gdb, the function is working properly. The error comes from an extra run through the while loop.

Comment: I'll show you where it gets called.

Comment: I'd put this in a debugger and verify `commandLineLength--; commandLine[ commandLineLength ] = 0;` is doing what you think it is, particularly if the `read` fails on the "second" iteration on inception and thus leaves `commandLineLength` as zero, thereby having you effectively do this: `commandLine[-1] = 0;`. That would be *bad*. This is what debuggers were *made* for.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. You need to extract a minimal but complete example. That said, many standard library implementations have diagnostic modes that help you find errors that cause undefined behaviour otherwise, like the negative index that WhozCraig pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

```
vector<string> split(string str, char delimiter) {
  vector<string> internal;
  stringstream ss(str); // Turn the string into a stream.
  string tok;

  while(getline(ss, tok, delimiter)) {
    internal.push_back(tok);
  }

  return internal;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to elaborate what you want to express with that answer and why. As it stands, it is not useful.

Comment: It's a replacement for your stringSplitter that should not invoke memory errors

Comment: You have neither explained why the original version causes memory errors nor have you explained why your version doesn't. Just that we understand each other, I don't think either version of the function causes errors, it's rather that the original poster is too lazy to actually extract a minimal example that would proof that the problem is somewhere else.